# Copy a JS Object from Service to Service using AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects

In a web application there are a wizard. The user in each page will select one or more rows from a table. There will be a Service which contains the selected row, one array for each table. In particular the Service will have:

```
    return {
    name: null,
    toys: [],
    foods: [],
    albums: []
   };
```

and when the user go forward in the next wizard page, there is a method which put the selected row in the array.

Now, what I want to do is to create a Service in the last page (which is a Summary page). This service will contain almost all of the other array Service. In particular, it will contain just toys[] and albums[]. 
So, the target is to create a Service and add a copy of toys[....all selected toys....] and a copy of albums[........all selected albums.....].

The problem, of course, is not to create a Service but to fill it with a copy of the array of the other Object. How can I do?

Comment: [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want app-level storage of these arrays. If that's indeed what you want, you can simply use a value to store these arrays and access it from any service, controller, whatever that you inject it into.

Something like:

```
.value("Storage", { toys: [], albums: [] })
.service("MyToysService", function(Storage) {
    this.addToy = function(toy) {
        Storage.toys.push(toy);
    }
})
```

You'll have full access to the **Storage** object and all of its arrays wherever you inject it. Changing it in one place will change it everywhere you use it because **Storage** is just an object.